# Mouseover not working with appended img-tag only with img-tag allready inside XHTML

Tags: jquery, image, tags, mouseover

i am really getting frustrated here. I have a XHTML with some div elements. When the page gets loaded i have some images that are beeing appended to the div tag inside my XHTML site. But when i try to catch an alert when hovering the img-tag it only works with the img tag that is allready inside my XHTML-Site. The mouseover won't catch any img-tag that are beeing appended. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
$('img').on("mouseover", function () {
    alert("Hi!");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery method .on() is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9. Try using .hover() instead.

```
$('img').hover(function() {
  alert("Hi!");
});
```

If it stil doesn't want to work try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').hover(function() {
    alert("Hi!");
  })
});
```